# Infinite loop in Bounded-waiting Mutual Exclusion with test and set

Tags: c, operating-system

In the book Operating System Concepts book of (Avi Silberschatz, Peter Baer Galvin, Greg Gagne) edition 9

In the process synchronization chapter, there is an algorithm for "Bounded-waiting Mutual Exclusion with test_and_set"

```
do {
    waiting[i] = true;
    while (waiting[i] && test_and_set(&lock)) ;
    waiting[i] = false;

    /* critical section */

    j = (i + 1) % n;
    while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
        j = (j + 1) % n; 
    if (j == i) 
        lock = false; 
    else
        waiting[j] = false;

    /* remainder section */
} while (true);
```

I understood the algorithm but why there is an infinite do-while loop??

Comment: It is to demonstrate a continuous process with critical section repeatedly acquiring the lock

Comment: Without any context I'd say that this could be some sort of server-like process and it must run and keep on providing its service?

Comment: Are you more generally asking why there's ever a need for an infinite loop? There are tons of applications, such as embedded systems and servers; consider every computing device that needs to continually run and perform a specific task. Not every computer is a desktop used for internetting.